# Null value in lambda expression - Entity Framework

Tags: c#, entity-framework, lambda

I need to get value for `OrgName` (it could be null value).

Problem is in my lambda expression, because `c.Organization` could be null as well. And if is null, I get an error. Do you have any idea, how can I accomplish this issue? Thanks

```
var users = _userManager.Users.Select(c => new UsersViewModel()
        {
            Id = c.Id,
            Username = c.UserName,
            Email = c.Email,
            Role = string.Join(",", _userManager.GetRolesAsync(c).Result.ToArray()),
            OrgName = _db.Organizace.FirstOrDefault(a => a.Id == c.Organization).OrgName.ToString()
        }).ToList();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would check for null inside the lambda.

```
var users = _userManager.Users.Select(c => new UsersViewModel()
{
    Id= c.Id,
    Username = c.UserName,
    Email = c.Email,
    Role = string.Join(",", _userManager.GetRolesAsync(c).Result.ToArray()),
    OrgName = c.Organization != null ? _db.Organizace.FirstOrDefault(a => a.Id == c.Organization).OrgName.ToString() : string.Empty
}).ToList();
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use null conditional operators:

```
OrgName = _db.Organizace.FirstOrDefault(a => a.Id == c.Organization)?.OrgName;
```

However, what you are doing is very inefficient and will result in many database calls.

You should explore using [navigation properties](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/ef6/fundamentals/relationships) and [includes](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/querying/related-data/eager#:%7E:text=can%20use%20the-,Include,-method%20to%20specify) instead to achieve the same behaviour in a more efficient manner.

Comment: Unfortunately this doesn't work. Because I had to manage null value in c.Organization .. but, thanx for the link, I`ll check it!

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
OrgName = _db.Organizace.FirstOrDefault(a => a.Id == c.Organization)?.OrgName
```